# Why is there no intercept in the lars output for LASSO in Stata?

Tags: stata, lasso, lars

This is my first time using lars, so this question is probably obvious.

When I run lars on my data I get an output with a model and coefficients assigned to predictors, but there is no intercept.

I thought part of how LASSO worked was shrinking coefficients, which to me would imply you need an intercept to make up for the shrinking coefficients.

Obviously I am missing something here, so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that centering both response & predictors is usual in LASSO because it puts the intercept - which you don't want to shrink - to zero before fitting. R's `lars` package does this by default, storing the response & predictor sample means (as well as the $L_2$-norms used for scaling) so that you can recover the intercept (by extracting them & calculating it, or by using @Dimitriy's neat `predict` method). I'm not familiar with Stata, but you should be able to recover the intercept by manual calculation at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lars` in Stata matches the defaults in R (standardize all variables to have unit L2 norm and include an intercept). The intercept itself, however, is not reported in either package. I think I figured out how to get it in R using `predict` and setting all the covariates to zero, but I can't seem to successfully replicate this with Stata.

Here's the Stata code (which calls R using `rsource` from SSC) showing the equivalence:

```
set more off
capture ssc install rsource
sysuse auto, clear
saveold "/Users/dmasterov/Desktop/auto_v12.dta", replace

rsource, terminator(END_OF_R) 

library(lars)
library(foreign)
data<-read.dta("/Users/dmasterov/Desktop/auto_v12.dta")
attach(data)
x<-data[c("mpg","headroom","trunk","weight","length","turn","displacement")]
x<-as.matrix(x)
y<-price
lars <- lars(x,y, type="lar", normalize = TRUE, intercept = TRUE)
lars
coefficients(lars)
summary(lars)
predict(lars,data.frame(mpg=0,headroom=0,trunk=0,weight=0,length=0,turn=0,displacement=0),s=7)$fit
detach(data)

END_OF_R

sysuse auto, clear

lars price mpg headroom trunk weight length turn displacement, algorithm(lars)
```

At first, my intuition was that you should be able to take the `lars` coefficients and use them in constrained regression in Stata to get the intercept. However, I cannot seem to match the number I get in R with this method. I get essentially the intercept you would get if you included no constant, but a vector of ones in X whose coefficients you penalized.